# Apache hive create table for given structure

Tags: hive

My csv file contains data structure like:

```
99999,{k1:v1,k2:v2,k3:v3},9,1.5,http://www.asd.com
```

what is the **create table** query for this structure?

I don't have to do any processing on csv file before it is loaded into table.

Comment: Just to get clear you have a csv of fields, one of them(coloumn:2) is Json?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Opencsv serde to read/write csv data to/from hive table. Download it here:https://drone.io/github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde/files/target/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar

*Add the serde to the library path of Hive.* - Could be skipped, but do upload it to the hdfs cluster your hive server is running. We will use it later to query.

**Create Table**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(a int, b string, c int, d double, url string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "'",
   "escapeChar"    = "\\"
)  
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Notice that  if you use openCSV serde, no matter what type you give, it will be taken as String by hive. But no worries as Hive is loosely type language. It will typecast string into int, json etc. at runtime.

**Query**

To query at the hive prompt first add the library if not added to the library path of hive

```
add jar hdfs:///user/hive/aux_jars/opencsv.jar;
```

Now you could query as:

```
select a, get_json_object(b, '$.k1') from my_table  where get_json_object(b, '$.k2') > val;
```

Above is the example to access the JSON field from an Hive table.

References:

1. http://documentation.altiscale.com/using-csv-serde-with-hive
2. http://thornydev.blogspot.in/2013/07/querying-json-records-via-hive.html

PS: Json Tuple is the faster way to access the json elements, but I found the syntax of get_json_object more appealing.

Comment: Thanks, but another problem coming up, in b it store {k1:v1 and c becomes null because it is defined as INT and k2:v2 is not int.